# Datalogger with interruputs

Tags: sd

I'm trying to do a data logger. Writes into SD card has to stop when `millis()`=1000. Maybe I have a problem between `millis()` and my interrupt, because datalogger doesn't stop after `millis()`=1000. I'm working with Arduino Mega.

```cpp
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>
volatile unsigned int cuenta = 0;
unsigned char contador = 0x00;
const int chipSelect = 53;
long currentMillis = 0;
long previousMillis = 0;
long interval = 1000;

void setup() {
  DDRA = B11111111;
  cli();//stop interrupts
  TCCR0A = 0;// set entire TCCR2A register to 0
  TCCR0B = 0;// same for TCCR2B
  TCNT0  = 0;//initialize counter value to 0
  // set compare match register for 10000khz increments
  OCR0A = 25;// = (16*10^6) / (1000*64) - 1 (must be <256)
  // turn on CTC mode
  TCCR0A |= (1 << WGM01);
  // Set CS01 and CS00 bits for 64 prescaler
  TCCR0B |= (1 << CS01) | (1 << CS00);
  // enable timer compare interrupt
  TIMSK0 |= (1 << OCIE0A);
  sei();//allow interrupts
  //periodo de cada pulso 255ms del tren total de pulsos aproximadamnte 255ms
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ;
  }
  Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");
  if (!SD.begin(chipSelect)) {
    Serial.println("Card failed, or not present");
    while (1);
  }
  Serial.println("card initialized.");
}


ISR(TIMER0_COMPA_vect) {
  cuenta++;
  if (cuenta > 9) {
    PORTA = ++contador;
    cuenta = 0;
  } else {
    PORTA = 0X00;
  }
}


void loop() {
  currentMillis = millis();
  if (currentMillis - previousMillis <= interval)
  {
    String dataString = "";
    for (int analogPin = 0; analogPin < 1; analogPin++) {
      int sensor = analogRead(analogPin);
      dataString = String(sensor);

      if (analogPin = 1) {
        dataString += ",";
      }
    }
    File dataFile = SD.open("datalog2.txt", FILE_WRITE);
    if (dataFile) {
      dataFile.println(dataString);
      dataFile.close();
      // print to the serial port too:
      Serial.println(dataString);
    }
    else {
      Serial.println("error opening datalog.txt");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `millis()` function is based on a counter which [is incremented by
the Timer 0 overflow interrupt](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/1.8.5/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/wiring.c#L42-L63). Since you reconfigured
that timer to never overflow, that counter is not incremented anymore.

If you want to configure an Arduino timer for your own purposes, you
have to either:

- use *any* timer other than Timer 0, or
- loose the Arduino standard timekeeping functions: `millis()`,
  `micros()` and `delay()`.

I would favor the first option, especially on the Mega which has quite a
few spare timers.